# Code to display a string without calling any methods or functions

Tags: popularity-contest

Write a code to display "I Love You". 
Without using any built-in tools or functions like `echo`, `System.out.println`, `printf`, ...

You are not allowed to directly call any function throughout the program execution, but the system environment or the compiler-generated code might do. This way, you can put your code in a `main` function or method that is called by the running environment, but your program should not further call any functions.

By the way, a function is not an instruction, nor a command nor an operator. So calling `sum(a, b)` is not valid, but making `a = b + c` is, even if the compiler reduces this to internal function calls.

This is a [popularity-contest](/questions/tagged/popularity-contest), so the valid answer with the most upvotes wins.

Comment: how about treating stdout as a file and writing to it?

Comment: You are not allowed to call any function

Comment: So you are excluding `c` and many other languages.

Comment: People here tend not to accept answers so early, since usually accepting an answer means that the contest is over.

Comment: You can use `cout <<< 'text here'` in c

Comment: And php `echo` is not a function, but a language construction. (http://pt1.php.net/echo < documentation)

Comment: What is so bad about this challenge?  Most languages won't be able to compete, but some are free to do so. For example, GolfScript works fine.  PHP also works fine (paste text into blank text file).  There are many other languages that can do this challenge, so why are there so many downvotes and close votes?

Comment: @Quincunx This got 2 close votes as "too broad" and 2 as "primary opinion based". I do not think that this is particularly a great challenge (it is boring for me, but I really liked the brainfuck answer). However, I do not think that it should be closed (and I will vote for a reopen if it get closed). Being not much interesting and/or boring is not a close reason, and frankly, I am seeing people closing questions just for the sake of being closed using some lame excuse just because they find them boring or impossible to do in their favorite language.

Comment: @Victor IMHO it is unclear what you are asking, especially seeing all the discussions whether `.` is a function in Brainfuck. IMHO it is not, but as long as you don't say what is a function, it can't be verified.

Comment: -1 because what's considered a function call is a slippery slope. Everything printed to the screen eventually goes through a system call to the OS.

Comment: Let the system make a function call, but only YOU are not allowed to call any function throughout the program execution.

Comment: @tohecz, it is not me who are asking this. But anyway, if people think that the question has problems and should be closed, normally it is adequate to drop a comment explaining why (like you and Cruncher, but none of the closers, did). Otherwise, there would be no real point in closing the question as no one would be saying to the OP what should be improved to make the question be reopened. Further, if the question has a minor problem or unclear point, people should ask or inform the OP first. In most questions, the OP fixes or clarifies the minor point quickly and no close-voting is needed.

Comment: @Victor I agree (well, I come from TeX.SE, and we prefer `comment->(improve or close)` over `downvote -> maybe comment -> close -> improve -> reopen`), so I agree that it's wrong to cast a close vote without a comment if the reason for closure is not 100% obvious (like duplicate, spam, ...).

Comment: @tohecz Yeah, and I believe that "fixing the question if you might do" is much better than just "close for some minor unimportant problem". By the way, I think that this question is boring, but I took the freedom to edit it anyway and now I think that it addresses the informed problems.

Comment: @Cruncher I edited the question. Is it better now?

Comment: @vengets this is a popularity contest so please accept the answer with the most upvotes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Html-asp- xhtml-tex-php.....

I didn't use any functions

```
I Love You
```

Comment: That is a polyglot. It's valid in php, html, xhtml, asp ...

Comment: valid in plain TeX as well, btw. And certainly doesn't use any functions, since there're no functions in the language at all.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel I agree but I'm not the one you should say that to. You should tell the OP.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel There! I fixed it.

Answer (score 10):

### Brainfuck

```
    ++++     ++++
  ++[>+++   ++++>++
 +>+++++++ ++++<<<-]
>+++.>++.<+++.>>+.+++
 ++++.--------------
   ---.<.<++++++++
     +++++.>>+++
      +++++++.+
        +++++
          .
```

The heart looks horribly thin here, but it is a lot better on a text editor / terminal

[image]

Here's a nicely indented version:

```
+++++ +++++ [
    > +++++ ++
    > +++
    > +++++ +++++ +
    <<< -
]
> +++ .
> ++ .
< +++ .
>> + .
+++++ ++ .
----- ----- ----- -- .
< .
< +++++ +++++ +++ .
>> +++++ +++++ .
+++++ + .
```

Comment: [There's a much shorter one](http://qp.mniip.com/p/56)

Comment: @mniip Length is not a concern in this question since it is not code golf. So I'd go for a slightly longer one, which makes it easier to make it look like a heart.

Comment: nicely indented version:) LOL

Comment: aren't "." equivalent to putchar, which is in terms of brainfuck like echo?

Comment: @V-X the OP said "no functions", and I'm quite certain there aren't any functions in brainfuck

Comment: isn't that build-in tool - command?

Comment: @V-X I don't know, but the OP seems to be okay with this

Answer (score 6):

## Javascript:

```
var l='I love you.';
if(window)window.status=l;
if(document)if(document.readyState=='complete')document.innerHTML=document.title=l;
else document.onload=function(){document.innerHTML=document.title=l;};
throw new l;
```

The part where it says 'function' is as ASSIGNMENT!

There is nothing in the question saying I can't assign functions and trigger events.

And the 'throw new l;' will say "I love you" in the error message.

This will show 'I love you' in the console, document, title and in the status bar.

Answer (score 4):

## C

```c
void main( )
{
  char *string="I Love You";
    volatile char *video = (volatile char*)0xB8000;
    while( *string != 0 )
    {
        *video++ = *string++;
        *video++;
    }
}
```

Comment: you are using the main function.

Comment: We are not allowed to call any function, Without main() how will you write a pgm ?

Comment: In this case gLibc calls `main()`

Comment: I don't know you wrote the question not me.

Comment: Nope, Read the question once again.. In this code no function call has been made. That's it..

Comment: @vengets `int main(){ printf("I love you"); }` I don't do any function call, that's the processor who does. (Almost like: "It's not my fault, it's the knive who killed that guy!")

Comment: printf() is a function, you are using it.. Problem here is u should not use it. (Let the processor call ..It doesnt matter..) Got it ??

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica, GolfScript, Python Interpreter, bc

This outputs the sentence:

```
"I love you"
```

Comment: Polyglot; works in GolfScript and Python Interpreter too. Works in PHP but outputs with the quotes.

Comment: Also works in `bc`.

Comment: @Quincunx, manatwork, I included the languages you mentioned in the title.

Answer (score 2):

## PHP

Quite rule bending maybe...

```
<? ?>I Love You
```

Answer (score 2):

## HTA - HyperText Application

```
I Love You
```

Microsoft says any plain text is valid HTA. They even mention in their official documentation that their "Hello, World." can be as simple as:

```
Hello, World.
```

Although most examples that you see on the web go the "official" route.

Answer (score 1):

### Shell Script

```
mkdir "I Love You"
cd I\ Love\ You/
pwd | grep -o '/I Love You' | cut -c2-
```

Answer (score 1):

## Smalltalk

as there is a read-eval-print-loop, and strings are self evaluating, this is trivial. From the command line, type this:

`stx -P "'I love you'`

A workspace, which is a basically a graphical wrapper for the `eval`, type in a string and select the "printIt" menu function.

Answer (score 1):

## DOS Command Prompt

```
C:> prompt I Love You
I Love You
```

Comment: I am wondering why my bold text is not as big and bold as others'.

Comment: Because they are not using a bold text,they are using headers. Try adding a # before the title. (remove the *)

Comment: Or put `========` under the title. Only one is enough, but I usually put the same number of `=` as the length of the title

Comment: is prompt not an external function?

Comment: Prompt is a command, but it's purpose is NOT to print strings.